# Regex match for php tags ignoring xml tags

Tags: regex

I want to throw validation error if -

- user input contains php tags `<?php` (also for short tags `<?`)
- but I want to allow XML tags (`<?xml`) if there are no php tags detected.
- In the presence of both, I would like to throw error.

I have been upto the following regex now -

```
`(.*?)<\?(php)?[^xml](.*?)`
```

But it does not match if the input contains only PHP short tags.

**I want to match the following -**

PHP Short tag

```
<?
```

PHP tag

```
<?php
```

PHP tag in the presence of xml tag

```
<?php ?>
<?xml
```

**Do not match the following**

```
<?xml
```

**Update**

Using this regex `(.*?)<\?[^x](.*?)` does not detect `<?` charater if the input contains only `<?`, without any ending whitespace. I guess I just need to add a condition in the following position to check further only if more characters are there -

```
         |
         v
`(.*?)<\?[^x](.*?)`
```

If I try with this - `(.*?)<\?([^x]?)(.*?)`, it no more excludes the `xml`. Do you see where I am hanging? I guess there is something which regex allows here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need regex at all? Why not just do:

```
if file contains '<?php'
    throw an error
if file contains '<?' but *doesn't* contain '<?xml'
    throw an error
```

**EDIT** as mentioned in comments this won't cover a file that contains `<?` and `<?xml` (although you could count the number of occurences of `<?` and if this is GREATER than the number of `<?xml`, then throw an error).

Re regex, you have a few options. If your regex flavour supports negative lookaheads, you can look for a `<?` that *isn't* followed by a 'x':

```
<\?(?!x)
```

or if it doesn't support negative lookaheads, you could try

```
<\?([^x]|$)
```

Either of these look for the presence of a PHP flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had initially done without regex when I had to check only for the presence of PHP tags. Later when I was needed to check additionally for XML tags, I went for regex. I guess, I am not very clear with the fundamentals of when to switch to regex matching. Will regex be an overkill in my case? Anyway, using this regex `(.*?)<\?[^x](.*?)` does not detect `<?` charater if the input contains only `<?`, without any ending whitespace. Any ideas?

Comment: if I use this logic `if (file contains '<?php') or (file contains '<?' but *doesn't* contain '<?xml')`, an input containing `<?` and `<?xml` does not throw error (this input does not throw error - `<?<?xml` ). I guess, if have to go for the non-regex check, I need to further check some position stuff or count of each matches. So, do you think regex check would be better in this case?

Comment: Great! It was negative lookahead that I was looking for. By the way, we have PHP 5 in the production. How to make sure before rollout though? Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

The regex you're looking for is:

```
/<\?(?!xml)(?:php|.{0,3})/s
```

Here is the PHP sample code:

```
if (preg_match("/<\?(?!xml)(?:php|.{0,3})/s", $str))
  echo "Not allowed\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind if you use the this regex:

```
<\?(?!x)
```

or

```
<\?([^x]|$)
```

you're still vulnerable when short_open_tags is enabled. This line will output Hello World:

```
<?xml_error_string(1); echo 'Hello World!'; ?>
```

I could only come up with this regex

```
<(\?([^x]|xml_.*?)|\%)
```

But then you're still left with this fragment...

```
error_string(1); echo 'Hello World'; ?>
```

I'm to tired for a better solution but it's still better then code that would run. ;-)

Comment: I think in OP's case, parsing the input is more appropried than using a regex.